# Printing a table in jquery

Tags: jquery, printing

I would like to print a table without the `edit | delete` button fields, and center the table in print.

I'm trying using this code, but the output print is not as I expected.

[Here is the output print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIwlc.png)

```
<table class="table"  border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Equipamento.Nome)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Colaborador)
        </th>
        <th style="align-content:center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Qtd)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataRequisicao)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Equipamento.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Colaborador)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataRequisicao)
            </td>

            <td id="x">
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.RequisicaoId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.RequisicaoId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.RequisicaoId })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
```

Here is the jquery script, I'm trying to use `$("#printTable tr td")` to hide the elements but it doesn't work.

```
<script>
    function printData() {
        var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
        newWin = window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $("#printTable tr td").each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function () {
                $(this).find("#x").toggleClass('hidden');
            });
        });
        printData();
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: print the table without the edit | delete button fields, and center the table in print.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're applying a class `hidden` with no accompanying css.

Try adding this block at the top of your file:

```
<style>
  .hidden { display: none; }
</style>
```